# Resources for WinForms/WPF dev trying to learn ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wpf, winforms, asp.net-ajax

What are your best resources for a WinForms/WPF developer to come up to speed on ASP.NET?  Will it take a complete paradigm shift for me to learn how to use ASP.NET or will it be a slight adjustment?

I will award the answer flag to the post with a resource that gets me up to speed in the shortest amount of time.  Downloadable code and code examples would be most helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Official ASP.NET Site](http://www.asp.net/) has [tutorials and videos](http://www.asp.net/Learn/)

[4 Guys From Rolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202742/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/) is a great resource, as is [Scott Guthrie's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/).

W3Schools has [tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/default.asp).

[There is  quite a bit of a shift towards ASP.NET MVC, so I would suggest you look at that]

Answer (score 0):

The are lots of resources on the web but I would definately recommend the Learn section of the ASP.NET Community Site: http://www.asp.net/learn/

I would also recommend [Professional ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 Edition: In C# and VB](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-ASP-NET-3-5-SP1-Edition-In-C-and-VB.productCd-0470478268.html) from Wrox.